# Loop through array of DIV ids, and refresh those DIVS every x seconds

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Say I have 4 divs:

```
<div id='blue'></div>
<div id='refresh12'></div>
<div id='red'></div>
<div id='refresh23'></div>
```

I'm putting every div on my page that begins with 'refresh' into an array like this:

```
var divs = $('div[id^="refresh"]');
```

Now, what I want to do, is refresh the divs in the array every 5 seconds.  I know I need to use SetInterval, but I'm not sure how to start the loop.  Also, the divs aren't pulling content from another page, it's from the same page, just dynamic data that needs to be refresh every 5 seconds.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where is div's data? If data getting with some function, you should call these functions not refresh divs.

Comment: Using PHP within the divs to get mysql data.

Comment: There isn't enough information to effectively give you a solution, for instance, where is the information that is going in to the div? You'll need to be able to point to it ie. $('div[id^="content"]') then use a loop to manage which content is going in to the div.

Comment: so basically is is from another page, since it's PHP/MySQL... the information won't be available without an ajax request or refresh

Comment: You have to get data from ajax call if you want to be refrehed without whole page refresh.

Comment: You can't reload a part of your page without *"pulling content from another page"*. You must have a script on server-side (PHP) which generates only the `<div>` content, and call it via Ajax.

Comment: Ok. I'm using .load(samepageurl.php)

Comment: I've got that part down, it's the looping through the array that I need help with.

Answer (score 2):

Using `setInterval` is [not always the best idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval#section_7), because if your operation takes long and is blocking, calls might stack up.

You can use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) calls like this to achieve what you want:

```
var divs = $('div[id^="refresh"]');

setTimeout(function refreshThem () {

    //code to refresh your divs
    divs.xy();

    setTimeout(refreshThem, 5000);

}, 5000);
```

or if you want the first refresh to run at once:

```
(function refreshThem () {

    //code to refresh your divs
    divs.xy();

    setTimeout(refreshThem, 5000);

})();
```

Basically when the refresh is finished, a new timeout is set up to run the same code again in 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
setInterval(function() {
$('div[id^="refresh"]').each(function(inx) {
// update each div here
});
},5000);
```

Comment: to update the div would I just add:

$(this).load(url); 

to this?

Comment: If you need to load a URL via an AJAX call, yes.  However, doing this many times within the setInterval of 5 seconds will probably cause overlap.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){   

     var int=self.setInterval(RefreshDivs,5000);     

});

function RefreshDivs(){

 // do your code to update/ refresh the div content. May be ajax call..

}
```

Comment: Passing a string to `setInterval()` is bad practice in most cases. Please don't suggest it. See [Efficient Javascript on Dev.Opera](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/efficient-javascript/?page=2#timeouts).

Comment: @bazmegakapa : Thanks for the link. I never knew.

Answer (score 0):

What you're going to need to do is something like

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('div[id^="refresh"]').each(function(i,el){
        $(el).load('pageURL ' + $(el).prop('id'));
    })
}, 500)
```

or as someone already stated, `setTimeout()`